# Difference between consecutive rows in table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need help calculating the difference between each row of data. The count increments and data is captured every hour.

```
+-------------------------+------------------+
|         t_stamp         |  qty             |
+-------------------------+------------------+
| 2020-01-08 19:00:00.007 |           514096 |
| 2020-01-08 20:00:00.007 |           514096 |
| 2020-01-08 21:00:00.003 |           514096 |
| 2020-01-08 22:00:00.003 |           514096 |
| 2020-01-08 23:00:00.013 |           514096 |
| 2020-01-09 01:00:00.003 |           531181 |
| 2020-01-09 02:00:00.003 |           531181 |
| 2020-01-09 03:00:00.000 |           531181 |
+-------------------------+------------------+
```

What I would like to return is:

```
+-------------------------+------------------+
|         t_stamp         | count_per_hr     |
+-------------------------+------------------+
| 2020-01-08 19:00:00.007 |                0 |
| 2020-01-08 20:00:00.007 |                0 |
| 2020-01-08 21:00:00.003 |                0 |
| 2020-01-08 22:00:00.003 |                0 |
| 2020-01-08 23:00:00.013 |                0 |
| 2020-01-09 01:00:00.003 |            17085 |
| 2020-01-09 02:00:00.003 |                0 |
| 2020-01-09 03:00:00.000 |                0 |
+-------------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (qty - lag(qty, 1, qty) over (order by t_stamp)) as diff
from t;
```

Note that this uses the 3-argument form of `lag()` to convert missing previous values (i.e. the first value) to a specified value.

Comment: Perfect, I've never used lag before. Thank you!